# Apache Virtual host alias: internal rewrite pages not working

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this configuration for my `site.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /websites/site.com

    Alias /project "/websites/site.com/project/public"

    <Directory "/websites/site.com/project/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /projects/logs/errors/site.com.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I need to be able to do the following:

1. When I go to **site.com**, serve the contents of the `DocumentRoot /websites/site.com` - **Check**
2. When I go to **site.com/project**, serve the contents of `/websites/site.com/project/public` - **Check**
3. When I go to **site.com/project/page**, serve the contents of `/websites/site.com/project/public/page.php` - ***Not working(page not found)***

Here is the .htaccess in `/websites/site.com/project/public`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Block access to hidden files and directories.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

Also, if I go to `site.com/project/page.php`, it works just fine, but obviously I want the extension gone.

Everything works fine if I move all the files out of the **public** directory in `/websites/site.com/project/public`, and put them just in `/websites/site.com/project`, but I don't want to do that because I want all my code to be outside of the root of the website.

The problem is that I need to show the project on the internet, and because I don't have a domain for it yet, I need to put it in a subdirectory of a existing domain.

I know there is a problem with the `Alias` in the virtual host configuration, and maybe with the `.htaccess`, but I can't figure what.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you!

Comment: "because I don't have a domain for it yet, I need to put it in a subdirectory of a existing domain" - any reason you don't create a separate subdomain (separate vHost, separate everything)?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve by moving `/websites/site.com/project` in `/websites/project`, basically moving the whole website out of the subdirectory of `site.com`.

Then in the configuration file, I replaced all paths to point to this new location and everything just works.

Can't say I fully understand why.

Comment: this worked just fine for me, I've been struggling for a while with this issue. you saved me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the Apache documentation you cannot combine Alias and Rewrite directives in the same context - the Alias directive will always be ignored.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html